# How to to add php-statements in an html file?

Tags: php, html

I tried to add the command  `<?php session_start(); ?>` before the first line of an `index.html` - file. Aside from that, the file only contains html statements.
When I noticed that the php-code was not getting interpreted, I changed the ending of the file to `index.php`, which solved that issue.

Now I am wondering whether what I did is an ugly hack or actually an accepted practice? Is it ok to add a php-prefix to a file that is otherwise html?

Also, I am sadly still getting the following error:
`session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent` . In case my above practice is fine, what causes this error?

Comment: not a hack, a fine practice, that or tell the server to parse *.html as *.php. as to the error - as it says, headers are already sent; the error should tell you where as well

Comment: Why not just call it `index.php`?

Comment: It all depends on what your are doing as a whole. Maybe explain more?

Comment: I found the error: There was a space before my `<php?` -statement. I actually did call the file index.php . I just wonder whether maybe the fact that a simple space can cause an error should be a hint to use a different practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is what you're meant to do.

Filesystem-based webservers, such as Apache and IIS (for the most part) interpret a requested file based on its file extension and process it accordingly. When a user requests a `.html` file then the server will return the raw bytes of the file, whereas if the user requested a `.php` file then it will run it through the PHP module or CGI program which generates the desired output.

You can configure your webserver (assuming you're not on a shared hosting service) to always process `.html` files with PHP, but it's better to hide implementation details in your URIs and use URL Rewriting instead (something Apache and IIS7+ have full support for).

With respect to the `session_start()` error you're getting - that's because `session_start` has to be called before anything is output to the client, which means that the `<?php session_start() ?>` part has to be at the very start of your document with no plaintext or blank-lines before it. You can have some PHP code before the call, but be sure that the PHP code is not sending any responses or headers.

Comment: Wow, I had one space before my `<?php` -statement. Removing this solved the issue. As mentioned above, it doesn't make me feel very comfortable about my approach that an additional space can cause such an issue.

Comment: Think about it this way: the first-pass PHP parser will read through your `.php` file one character at a time. If a character is not within a `<? ?>` block then it will be output to the client. That's why `<?` has to be at the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Keep  in mind that .php Files should parse through both PHP & HTML Tags.  Placing a  tag at the begining of the document is a common practice.

Also like @markus-tharkun mentioned - it really depends on what you are trying to do with the PHP code.  If you just wanted to put a Timestamp in a Header of your HTML Doc it could be as simple as the following:

```
<h2>
  <?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); //Prints Date inside the H2 Tag ?> 
</h2>
```

Once again, i could put this code anywhere inside my  Tag and it would print out the current date using PHP.  *PHP can play interesting tricks with scope therefore it should always be paid close attention to.*

Comment: Your first sentence is interesting. So you are saying a *.php - file is to by convention understood as an html - file that additionally includes php-statements?

Comment: From my understanding & education - *.php File can contain HTML and will effectively parse through them IF THEY ARE SETUP CORRECTLY.  
`i.e - either by using Echo 'html here'; or by closing your <?php ?> tag & opening on the HTML Tag.`
**My Php HTML Files often resemble this basic outline:**
`<?php _PHP CODE HERE_ ?>
<html>
<head> HTML HEAD CONTENT HERE
</head><body>HTML BODY CONTENT</body></html>